# How to identify if a mouseEvent object came from a onclick or from a onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following javascript code:

```
document.body.onclick = fn
document.body.onmouseover = fn

function fn(mouseEvent) {
  ...
}
```

How to identify if the `mouseEvent` object came from a `onclick` or from a `onmouseover`? Does `mouseEvent` contain this information somewhere?

ps: I am aware I could do something like this, but it's a lot of boilerplate.

```
document.body.onclick = fnOnclick
document.body.onmouseover = fnOnMouseover

function fn(mouseEvent, source)
function fnOnclick(mouseEvent) { fn(mouseEvent, "onclick") }
function fnOnmouseover(mouseEvent) { fn(mouseEvent, "onmouseover ") }
```

Comment: There's `event.type`.

Comment: `console.log(mouseEvent)` you can see a lot of interesting information

Comment: Or read it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) ...

Comment: [`Event.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type) it supported on every browser except IE

Comment: @CodeManiac It is supported in IE too.

Comment: @Teemu MDN says not fully supported [Event.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @CodeManiac Does it? It looks like MDN says "Compatibility unknown" ..? It is also documented in an IE documentation from year 1999 = ).

Comment: Thanks @Teemu. I did read that page before posting here, but I didn't realize that you need to click on all superclasses to find out all the events. (`type` is defined in Event, not in MouseEvent). A javadoc/scaladoc for a class lists the functions of all superclasses also.

Comment: I have never head of event.type not being fully supported. I remember scripts from the nineties that were a single handler for all click events, switching on type